# How to detect if a website is loaded within an iOS WebView using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ios, webview

I'm creating a very basic app within Xcode to load my already existing web app into a webview.

I require my web app to check if it has been loaded within an iOS webview so that it can apply difference styles and a few other things.

**What I have tried so far:**

I tried echoing `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` with PHP, yet it was blank.

I tried comparing the results of `navigator.userAgent`, yet there are only very small differences, which may conflict with versions of Safari and Chrome.

**Result of `navigator.userAgent` from iOS Xcode Simulator:**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13C75
```

**Result of `navigator.userAgent` from Google Chrome iOS simulator:**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1
```

How can I check, with either Javascript of PHP, if my website is loaded within an iOS webview?